# Why 2 1600MHz Makes 1333MHz & How to fix it?

Tags: windows, memory, windows-8.1, ddr

I have **4GB DDR3 1600MHz** Ram in my laptop(Dell Vostro). I bought another **4GB DDR3 1600MHz** Ram and put it to my laptop.

Now my laptop shows 8GB Ram as expected. But it show 1333MHz. Why is that? How to fix it?

Comment: Model of laptop?

Comment: @Appleoddity Dell Vostro 3559

Comment: Where does it show this? How do we know what you are looking at?

Comment: @Mark It is showing in  Task Manger -> Performance Tab

Comment: @Mark if you click the memory meter on the performance tab it will bring up a larger memory graph in the main window area. Below the two graphs there on the right hand side will be "Speed:" as well as slots used.

Comment: @Mark Even you write a wrong comment, don't delete it. People don't know everything. It is totally fine. Next time, don't delete comments.

Answer (score 0):

Clock speed is not the only important memory "speed" you need to look at when buying memory to go with old sticks.

If you do not have a matched pair of DIMMs then they may have different memory timings (CAS, RAS, etc), as a result your memory controller may have to work to a "highest common settings" at a lower frequency.

It is often best to get a DIMM that as closely matches the make and model of your existing set in order to ensure they are 100% compatible.

That said, if your machine was in single channel and is now dual then 2 x 1333 (2666) will still be faster than 1 x 1600. Memory accesses should still be effectively faster.

Im sure at one point I have seen machines which listed both a maximum memory speed as well as a maximum "fully populated" memory speed. I can't find the source where I read that caveat at the moment.

Comment: `That said, if your machine was in single channel and is now dual then 2 x 1333 (2666) will still be faster than 1 x 1600. Memory accesses should still be effectively faster.` Which means, it is better having two 4GB 1600MHz (because *2= 3200Mhz) Rams than one 8GB 1600mHz Ram.

Comment: @Damith yes, dual channel will result in higher peak bandwidth than single channel. I would prefer a slightly lower clocked dual channel over single channel. 2 DIMMs are better than 1.

Comment: @Damith you can use CPU-z (https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) and check the memory tab, it should tell you the memory configuration (single or dual) as well as other details of the memory modules itself.